# how to inject a generic class in another generic class in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have three class, the hierachy like this, it runs fine.

```
/** the basic service class, it inject the M generic class */    
public class service<M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> implements ...{
    
    @Autowire
    M mapper;
    
    protected M getMapper(){
        return this.mapper;
    }
}

/**
    the ParentClass extends the Service Class
*/
public class ParentClass< M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> extends service<M,T>
{
    
}

/**
    the ChildClass extends the ParentClass and pass the entity class to parentclass
*/
@Service
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass<UserMapper,User>{
    
}
```

now I want inject another generic class Query into the ParentClass like this.

```
public class ParentClass< M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> extends service<M,T>
{
    @Autowire
    Query<M,T> query;
}
```

1. the first situation, because I need inject the Query class into the ParentClass, so the Query class must be a bean,
   if I add the @component annoation in the Query class, the springboot will prompt there are too many implements of BaseMapper(because the are too many implements of BaseMapper in my project, and the M is generic type, springboot don't know which Mapper will be used), so I think it's not the right way to add @component to the Query class.

Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.feiji.framework.library.crud.Query required a single bean, but 96 were found:

```
@Component
public class Query<M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> implements IQuery<M,T>{
    
    @Autowire
    M mapper
    
}
```

2. change the mapper a constructor parameter to the Query class, and Instantiate the Query class in the setMapper method, It work fine, but I want the Query object is injected by spring rather than manually create;

```
@Component
public class Query<M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> implements IQuery<M,T>{
    
    
    private M mapper
        
    public Query(M mapper){
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }    
    
} 

public class ParentClass< M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> extends service<M,T>
{
    
    Query<M,T> query;
    
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void setQuery(){
        query = new Query(getMapper());
    }
}
```

3. use the @Bean annotation to make the query class manage by springboot, and then use the @Autowire to inject the Query class to ParentClass, it's work fine too , but I think it's stupid way.

```
@Configurable    
public class ParentClass< M extends BaseMapper<T>,T> extends service<M,T>
{
    @Autowire
    @Lazy
    Query<M,T> query;
    
    
    @Bean
    public Query setQuery(){
        return new Query(getMapper());
    }
}
```

could any one give me some suggestion for this problem, thanks.

Comment: Is it not possible to specify which query object you want to inject using @Qualifier annotation?